Man trying to save himself from cops
I watched the movie very long ago (Around 90s) so forgive me if I am not very detailed.
The main character of the movie was a target between cops and the government. They wanted him dead but as he was really clever he had told the media all about it. At a scene he had captured a president of an African country and the police tried to kill the guy behind the curtain but they killed the president instead.
Final scene was the main character going to enter a helicopter on foot very slowly and calm but suddenly the cops decided to shoot him and that was the end. 

Once someone told me that it is one of Alain Delon's movies... i don't know.

It is french movie "The Professional" from 1981, with Jean Paul Belmondo in the leading role.

French secret agent Josselin Beaumont is sent to kill Colonel Njala, the dictator of Malagawi, a fictional African country. However, before he manages to accomplish his mission, the political situation changes drastically and the French secret service resorts to handing over Beaumont to the Malagawian authorities. After a long, unfair trial, during which Beaumont is injected with drugs, he is sentenced to long-term penal servitude at a "re-education camp".
  Following a daring escape with one of the other inmates, he returns to France and informs the French secret service of his presence, promising that he will kill Njala, who is in France for an official visit, thus getting his revenge on the people who betrayed him. The secret service responds by setting other agents on Beaumont's trail. However, he manages to remain one step ahead, humiliating and killing some of his major betrayers, including Rosen, the sadistic chief of the secret police. After Rosen falls in a gunfight, Beaumont switches their identity cards, spreading confusion within the secret service and temporarily reducing Njala's guard. Beaumont eventually tricks a secret service agent into shooting the dictator. While government officials confer with higher authorities, he slowly walks towards Njala's helicopter, but is shot dead by government agents, who have received the order to do so.

Here you can see the final scene from movie.
